# How do I make a query into a field in Django

Tags: sql, django, database

This is probably a very simple question but I can't figure it out. The way my User model is set up is that they have a Profile attached to it and in the Profile there is a value for Coins.

I would like to return the top 10 users by coins so I thought that something like: `User.objects.all().order_by('coins')[:10]` would work, but the problem is that the coins are attached to the profile.

`.order_by('profile.coins')` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: FYI, you can also extend the regular User model by extending a class called `AbstractUser`. Then, you could just add whatever fields you like without this whole profile business. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the double underscore notation in querysets if you want to traverse relationships:

```
User.objects.order_by('profile__coins')[:10]
```

Relevant documentation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Those relationships can be as deeply nested as you like, but keep in mind that deep nesting can severely impact your performance by creating complex sql joins.